# How to add geolocation to weatherwidget-io

Tags: javascript, html, widget, weather, weather-api

I have added the weatherwidget-io weather app to my website and I want to add geolocation to this instead of having a fixed location. So any user coming on to my website will see the weather for their location.

HTML and JS code :

```
<a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/55d95n3d19/edinburgh/" data-label_1="EDINBURGH" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-theme="original">EDINBURGH WEATHER</a>
</div>
<script>
!function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }
}(document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) to request the user's location. From this you can get the user's latitude and longitude coordinates. Then you can use [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) to get the city for that particular coordinates. Then you can use that information to request the city's weather from the weatherwidget-io weather app.